# No module named 'utils'

Tags: python

I am new to the world of python. I am trying to learn first order logic from https://github.com/aimacode/aima-python/blob/master/logic.ipynb

I just follow the same steps as mentioned but I get the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

[image]

I use Jupyter notebook for the testing purpose. I can see there are questions related to this error. But still I could not solve it.
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clone the whole Github repo, not only download (or copy from) the Notebook.

See `utils.py` is a separate file.

https://github.com/aimacode/aima-python/blob/master/utils.py

Also refer to [Installation Guide](https://github.com/aimacode/aima-python#installation-guide)